# Issues with offsetTop when HTML margin is applied

Tags: javascript, html, positioning

if I set this CSS

```
html {
    margin: 10px;
    border 10px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and then try to get `offsetTop` of some element, is it possible to convince browsers (IE and CH) not to ignore document `margin` in the calculation? Firefox works as expected reporting values according to rendered HTML (uses all three values).

**Is there a fast cross-browser way** of calculating `offsetTop` when `offsetParent` is actually `BODY`. Unfortunately jQuery's `.offset()` doesn't do the trick here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This code](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticlePageOffset) will get you thinking and started.

The idea is to use `HTMLElement.getBoundingClientRect()` function that's supported by all major browser these days (and has been for quite some time now). The only difference I've found out was when running it against `document.documentElement` element. FF and Chrome don't report bottom values according to view port but rather to whole document itself.

So be careful.